# how to remove all files from hdfs location except one?

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs

I want to remove all files from hdfs location except one, But unable to find any solution for it.

i have tried `shopt -s extglob` then `hadoop fs -rm location/!(filename)`
but it did not work.

Comment: why dont you move this files on another location and then copy back to original location after deleting other files

Comment: thanks for the response. It is possible that way but i have to perform this operation on over 100 of table location in hdfs .so it will be more time consuming this way.

Answer (score 2):

A best option would be to copy specific file to some other directory and delete all the remaining files in target directory and then move specific file to the same directory.

Else, There are couple of other ways as well to do the same thing.

Below is one sample shell script to delete all the files expect one matching pattern.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Executing the shell script"

for file in $(hadoop fs -ls /user/xxxx/dev/hadoop/external/csvfiles |grep -v 'a_file_pattern_to_search' | awk '{print $8}')
do
    printf '\n' >> "$file"
    hadoop fs -rm "$file"
done
echo "shell scripts ends"
```

List all the files and then using grep with -v option which get all the files other than your specific pattern or a filename.

Comment: Thanks for the response @vikrant rana. The code is working fine, But the above code is more time consuming as it will run the `hadoop fs -rm`  command for every file rather than all unwanted files. there are  more than 2000 files in location .above code will execute the `hadoop fs -rm` command for every unwanted file. is it possible to provide any pattern in the `hadoop fs -rm` to remove the file except the one ?

Comment: @kishorahire it is not possible to use negative pattern in hadoop fs -rm

Comment: Rather than removing files one by one i have created array before the for loop and append all the results to that array. After completion of for loop i have executed `hadoop fs -rm` command on whole array . now it is much faster than removing the file in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution following vikrant rana's one. It does not require rm command to execute multiple times, and also doesn't need to store the files in any array, reducing loc and efforts:

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/xxxx/dev/hadoop/external/csvfiles| grep -v 'a_file_pattern_to_search'  | awk '{print $8}' | xargs hadoop fs -rm
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code i'am able to remove all files from hdfs location at once except the file which is needed.

```
file_arr=()
for file in $(hadoop fs -ls /tmp/table_name/ | grep -v 'part-' | awk '{print $8}')
do
    file_arr+=("$file")
done
hadoop fs -rm "${file_arr[@]}"
```